# IIS on Virtual Computer

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, virtual-machine

I'm new here. I'm developing some Asp.Net applications and i wanna test them on my virtual IIS. I have installed Windows 7 and enabled IIS features on a VmWare virtual computer. I'm using IIS 7 recommend configuration and my virtual computer have a real internet network IP. I wanna explore my websites via writing my virtual computer's IP to my browser. How can i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335585/accessing-host-machine-iis-from-a-guest-os-in-vmware

Comment: If you open the browser in your virtual machine and type `http://localhost`, do you see a web page? If so: If you open the browser on your host machine and type `http://IP-Address-of-VM`, do you see a web page? If so: go on and ask real programming questions. If not, please ask your questions in `webmasters.stackexchange.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure your VMWare machine has a network interface that allows it access to the host. So, in other words: the two machines (host and virtual machine) must be able to "see" each other on the network.

Next, open a Cmd window on the virtual machine and execute `ipconfig`. That will tell you the IP address of the virtual machine.

Next, ping that IP address. It should work.

If it does, try to access the website on the virtual machine by typing the IP address into a browser on the host machine.

Comment: I'm able to ping virtual computer from my host but virtual server hosting more than one asp.net appplication and i'm unable to reach that applications by typing IP into browser.

Comment: Then you need to know the full URL of the application. On the virtual server, start up IIS Manager and use it to Browse to the Web application of your choice (for instance, http://localhost/MyApp). Then you use that URL on the host but replace localhost by the IP address of the virtual machine, so http://i.p.add.ress/MyApp.

Comment: When i Browse, address  is not like locakhost/MyApp, it's like localhost:80 but when i type it into my web browser from host i'm still unable to reach that page